# Installing Symfony project with PHP 7.3 version

Tags: php, symfony

Tryng to install (and after updating composer):

```
composer create-project symfony-cmf/sandbox cmf-sandbox
```

I have those errors:

```
Installing symfony-cmf/sandbox (2.0.0)
  - Installing symfony-cmf/sandbox (2.0.0): Loading from cache
Created project in cmf-sandbox
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.3.0 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.3.0].
    - phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.3.0 requires php ^5.6|7.0.x|7.1.x -> your PHP version (7.3.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.3.0 requires php ^5.6|7.0.x|7.1.x -> your PHP version (7.3.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.4.2 requires phpcr/phpcr-utils ^1.2.8 -> satisfiable by phpcr/phpcr-utils[1.3.0].
    - Installation request for doctrine/phpcr-odm 1.4.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-odm[1.4.2].
```

Edit: Continuing the recommendation of Timo, I was able to install the project by executing the following:

```
composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs symfony-cmf/sandbox cmf-sandbox
```

but I have obtained the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/src/ChainRouter.php:101
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/src/ChainRouter.php(308): Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter->all()
#1 /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(1670): Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter->setContext(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext))
#2 /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(335): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getCmfRouting_RouterService()
#3 /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(4955): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cmf_routing.rou...')
#4 /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(33 in /srv/http/symfony/cmf-sandbox/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/src/ChainRouter.php on line 101
```

The project uses a Symfony version 3 structure and may have some incompatibility with PHP 7.3 (as Timo says).

Comment: Checking the package `phpcr/phpcr-utils` on packagist, version `1.3.0` only supports php 5.6 - 7.1. Version `1.3.1` seems to be supporting PHP 7.x so that should work.

Comment: Still having trouble?  Does not seem to be a great deal of maintenance going on.  I have had some trouble with just the core Symfony framework on php 7.3.  Might try php 7.2 or even 7.1 and see what happens.  Just guessing.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I've installed phpcr-utils 1.4.0 by composer require phpcr/phpcr-utils but I have the same problem when i try install cmf-sandbox project: phpcr/phpcr-utils 1.3.0 requires php ^5.6|7.0.x|7.1.x -> your PHP version (7.3.0) does not satisfy that requirement. I try after restarting server and also after rebooting.

Comment: Thank you Cerad for your contribution, but right now I have several projects that depend on version 7.3 and it does not compensate me to download it for this pedagogical project.

Comment: Fair enough.  PHP did introduce some breaking changes (technically they are fixes).  In fact, the count warning in your updated question was introduced in php7.2 and broke alot of stuff.  There is a chat channel for cmf.  Might have better luck there.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, I'll see there

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Composer to ignore the PHP version requirements by adding `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the `composer create-project` command.

Else, you'll probably have to wait until the dependencies of `symfony-cmf/sandbox` get bumped to a later version.

Edit: If the latest release of Symfony CMF Sandbox doesn't work yet, you may try the master (latest unreleased changes) to see if they've been addressed there yet. You can do this by adding `--stability=dev` to your `composer create-project` command and using `symfony-cmf/sandbox:dev-master` as source instead:
`composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs --stability=dev symfony-cmf/sandbox:dev-master cmf-sandbox`

Comment: Thanks Timo, I have managed to install the project, however, it launches a series of errors both when finishing the installation and when executing the project. I edit in the exposition of my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the next option you can try: checking out the master branch instead of the latest release.

Comment: Thanks again Timo, Now I have been able to install it without problem with PHP 7.3 using your sentence. I had to modify the open_basedir of php.ini so that it could start.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that using the `dev-master` might not be stable enough for production. Keep an eye out for releases on `symfony-cmf/sandbox` and switch back to the latest release once they've published it.

Comment: Ok Timo, I'll do